# Pass arguments on BottomNavigationView using Navigation architecture

Tags: android, architecture, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I want to pass data to the BottomNavigationView using Navigation Architecture. I have one tab that when the user clicks it, I've done this via bundle and using safe args, however with the implementation that I currently have for my BottomNavigation View I don't know how to implement it.

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment_container)
        // Set up navigation menu
        bottom_navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

And the menu for the BottomNavigationView is the following:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mainEventsFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/title_home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/notificationsFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications"
        android:title="@string/title_notifications" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/inboxFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_message"
        android:title="@string/title_messages" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/currentUserProfileFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_face"
        android:title="@string/title_profile" />

</menu>
```

How can I pass information when the user press the currentUserProfileFragment?